# creating a background view in paint

Tags: android, paint

I have a text and on the background of which a box should be painted in blue , such that that boz will look like below

/-------------------------------\

consider the broken line to be a solid line. My text should come under the top solid line.

The Horizontal line should be joined with the inclined vertical lines  and there should be text under horizontal line

Comment: What did you do yourself?

Comment: @hasanghaforian I have no idea as how to create inclined lines, inputs are highly appreciated